# Vugen version 12.60 failed to open, Displays an error

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

Is there anyone who experienced or know how to fix this issue we're facing when trying to open vugen?

It displays error message, please see screenshot below:

[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwdbd.png)

[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NtS3.png)

[Error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGNDo.png)

We've tried to end the process in task manager, restart the remote, uninstall then install the loadrunnner, but none of them work.

Comment: If you can please upgrade to 12.63 as there was an issue in that area that was resolved. Meanwhile you can try to delete the .sdf file from the script directory. Please comment if it solved the issue.

Comment: Hi buzzy, I tried deleting the .sdf file but it didn't work tho. I haven't tried to upgrade the version of LR, but will advise first our team if it is applicable to update it since the license that we have is for 12.60 version.

Comment: I think that since 12.63 is a minor patch the license should be fine but I am not sure.